# Unable to compile Intel MKL test codes with CMakeLists

Tags: c++, cmake, blas, intel-mkl

This is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "icpc")
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

project(example)

include_directories("/usr/include/eigen3")

find_package(BLAS)
include_directories(${BLAS_LIBRARIES_DIRS})
set(PROJECT_LIBS ${BLAS_LIBRARIES})


add_executable(example example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example ${PROJECT_LIBS})
```

And I got the error in `make` and also several lines same as following:

```
example.cpp:(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to `MKL_malloc'
example.cpp:(.text+0xde7): undefined reference to `MKL_free'
```

What should I do now?

The full codes of example.cpp:

```
#define min(x,y) (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mkl.h"

int main()
{
    double *A, *B, *C;
    int m, n, k, i, j;
    double alpha, beta;

    m = 2000, k = 200, n = 1000;
    alpha = 1.0; beta = 0.0;

    A = (double *)mkl_malloc( m*k*sizeof( double ), 64 );
    B = (double *)mkl_malloc( k*n*sizeof( double ), 64 );
    C = (double *)mkl_malloc( m*n*sizeof( double ), 64 );
    if (A == NULL || B == NULL || C == NULL) {
      mkl_free(A);
      mkl_free(B);
      mkl_free(C);
      return 1;
    }

    printf (" Intializing matrix data \n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < (m*k); i++) {
        A[i] = (double)(i+1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (k*n); i++) {
        B[i] = (double)(-i-1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (m*n); i++) {
        C[i] = 0.0;
    }

    cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, 
                m, n, k, alpha, A, k, B, n, beta, C, n);

    mkl_free(A);
    mkl_free(B);
    mkl_free(C);

    printf (" Example completed. \n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if I need more definitions in cmakelist, but I already found mkl.h in it.

By the way, I'm using ubuntu 16.04, the default compiler is g++, I'm trying to switch the compiler in order to utilize the intel mkl.

Comment: Please, for completeness add to the question post the code of `example.cpp` and the **exact command line**, used for linking (you may get this command line by running `make VERBOSE=1`).

Comment: My bad, already updated the full version codes.

Comment: And what about the **exact command line** I asked in the previous comment?